# Restarting a java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I was wondering why The ExecutorService can actually execute the same Thread multiple times.
Because the usual lifecycle of a thread ends on TERMINATED afaik..

So,

```js
public class TestThread extends Thread {

  AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.printf("%d\n", counter.addAndGet(1));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    TestThread t = new TestThread();

    es.execute(t);
    es.execute(t);

    es.shutdown();
  }
}
```

this works where i would actually expect an illegal state exception like in this case:

```
t.start();
t.start(); =>BAM!
```

Help much appreciated to unravel the magic behind the execute!

Comment: System.out.printf("%d\n", counter.addAndGet(1));. It will not show you usage of the same thread. You should use  Thread.currentThread().getId().

Comment: And there, we have another example why it was a big mistake to let `Thread` implement `Runnable`…

Comment: it was a big mistake to let Thread implement Runnable… Why???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ExecutorService does not ever re-start a Thread.  A Thread can never be re-started.

An ExecutorService is a thread *pool*.  It manages a set of long-running threads, and each thread is capable of performing many tasks.

When your code calls `es.submit(r)` for some ExeuctorService, es, and some Runnable, r; the submit function adds your runnable to a blocking queue.

Each of the threads managed by the ExecutorService has a run() method that looks like this:

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        Runnable task = queue.take();
        task.run();
    }
}
```

Of course really, it's more complicated than that because of exceptions and because of the shutdown() mechanism, but that's the basic idea.  The pool threads basically run forever, waiting for tasks to perform.

Comment: tyvm! that answers it

Answer (score 5):

The [`ExecutorService.execute(Runnable)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute%28java.lang.Runnable%29) wraps them with new `Thread` instances. If you also print the thread id,

```
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.printf("%d %d%n", counter.addAndGet(1),
        Thread.currentThread().getId());
}
```

You will see two different Thread(s) are running. For example,

```
1 10
2 11
```

Answer (score 2):

The `start()` method of your Thread object isn't invoked twice, not even once actually: only the `Runnable` interface of your object is used. Actual `Thread`s are created with each `execute()`, each delegating to your `run()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can not restart thread, but you can detect threads that were used multiple times;)

Test code:

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

public class TestOfCachedThreadPool {
  private static final int AMOUNT = 1000000;

  private static final class TestThread implements Runnable {
    private Map<Long, Long> mapOfUsage;

    private TestThread(Map<Long, Long> mapOfUsage) {
      this.mapOfUsage = mapOfUsage;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      synchronized (mapOfUsage) {
        Long numberOfThreads=mapOfUsage.get(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        if(numberOfThreads==null){
          mapOfUsage.put(Thread.currentThread().getId(), 1l);
        }else{
          mapOfUsage.put(Thread.currentThread().getId(), ++numberOfThreads);
        }
      }

    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadFactory threadFactory = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();
    final Map<Long, Long> mapOfUsage = new HashMap<>(AMOUNT * 2);
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    for(int i=0;i<AMOUNT;i++){
      service.execute(threadFactory.newThread(new TestThread(mapOfUsage)));
    }
    for(Map.Entry<Long, Long> entry: mapOfUsage.entrySet()){
      if(entry.getValue()>1){
        System.out.println("Thread with id "+entry.getKey() +" was used "+entry.getValue()+ " times");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

> Thread with id 9 was used 27198 times
>
> Thread with id 11 was used 1810 times
>
> Thread with id 13 was used 1294 times
>
> Thread with id 15 was used 3347 times
>
> Thread with id 17 was used 6709 times
>
> Thread with id 19 was used 7259 times
>
> Thread with id 21 was used 39335 times
>
> Thread with id 23 was used 13552 times
>
> Thread with id 25 was used 535 times
>
> Thread with id 27 was used 19533 times
>
> Thread with id 29 was used 113495 times
>
> Thread with id 31 was used 62713 times
>
> Thread with id 35 was used 94103 times
>
> Thread with id 33 was used 53641 times
>
> Thread with id 5328 was used 18922 times
>
> Thread with id 16388 was used 28501 times
>
> Thread with id 16384 was used 114677 times
>
> Thread with id 16386 was used 39 times
>
> Thread with id 16698 was used 60450 times
>
> Thread with id 123096 was used 19944 times
>
> Thread with id 123102 was used 60961 times
>
> Thread with id 123115 was used 24246 times
>
> Thread with id 275492 was used 108399 times
>
> Thread with id 275490 was used 11973 times
>
> Thread with id 380143 was used 10433 times
>
> Thread with id 363358 was used 55989 times
>
> Thread with id 692626 was used 6016 times
>
> Thread with id 909079 was used 25782 times
>
> Thread with id 965801 was used 32 times
>
> Thread with id 948919 was used 1782 times
>
> Thread with id 948872 was used 4 times
>
> Thread with id 938802 was used 24 times
>
> Thread with id 923558 was used 7302 times